# Are there generic instructions for authenticating a website using Python and Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a simple guide for secondary school students on how to use Python and requests/lxml to scrape website data. Unauthenticated scraping is trivial but I wanted to challenge some students to perform scraping of a site which they have to log into. I've done this before using csrf token...

```
auth = {
  'user_login_form[_username]'      : 'user@email.com',
  'user_login_form[_plainPassword]' : 'secret_password',
  'user_login_form[csrf_token]'     : 'token'
  }
login_url = 'https://website.com/login_check'
session = requests.Session()
a = session.post(
  login_url,
  data=auth
  )
print('Connecting to site ...',a.ok)
```

...but

1. I can't remember where I found the token
2. I think this is very specific to the website I was accessing.

So, is there a pattern/set of instructions for Python/requests that are generic enough to apply to most/all websites?

Comment: Are you asking about generating a token in python?

Comment: The first line of example code in the official docs of requests demonstrates how to pass credentials.

Comment: No, logging into a website with a username and password with requests so you can scrape authenticated content.

Comment: so is it simply a case of finding the login url of the site and passing the user and pass?

Comment: I recommend reading the authentication section of the requests documentation